# Qual é a origem de "bate-papo"?

Tags: etimologia, português-brasileiro, origem

A palavra [**bate-papo**](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/bate-papo) é frequentemente utilizada no Brasil como referência a uma conversa informal. É muito vista também em *sites* que oferecem [*chat online*](https://badoo.com/pt/bate-papo/).

Quando e onde tal expressão surgiu?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Por incrível que pareça, o *papo* do *bate papo* tem origem em *papar* (*comer*, Houaiss e ver [Aulete digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/papo)), que já vem do latim *pappare*. De *papar* veio [*papo* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/papo) com o sentido de papo de ave, estômago, barriga e, o sentido que aqui mais nos interessa, garganta. A certa altura passou também a significar ‘fanfarronice, bazófia, bravata’, significado que *garganta* também tem [(ver *garganta* no Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/garganta). Por fim veio a significar simplesmente ‘conversa’.

*Papo* aparece traduzido para latim como *guttur* [(*garganta*, Wikitionary)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guttur) neste [dicionário de 1562 de Jerónimo Cardoso](http://purl.pt/15192/3/#/164) (p. 83 do orginal, p. 165 do pdf). *Papo* aparece com este significado já em 1437 no [*Leal Conselheiro* do Rei D. Duarte (p. 301, ou 347 do pdf):](http://www.alvarenga.net/lealconselheiro.pdf)

> Item se deuem de guardar cantar de lyngua, nẽ de desuairamento de boca , mas soomente cantem de ***papo*** cada huũ melhor q poder.

Em 1720 Raphael Bluteau regista no seu [*Vocabulario Portuguez e Latino*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=EDa_AuDUJawC&pg=PA241&dq=%22fallar%20de%20papo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCxKS40ffLAhWC6xoKHYzbDUUQ6AEINTAD#v=onepage&q=%22fallar%20de%20papo%22&f=false) a expressão ***falar de papo***:

> **Fallar de papo**, se diz de quem falla com certo geyto na garganta , que denota presumpçaõ , e arrogancia.

Mas já em 1651 se encontra o adágio de António Delicado, «moço de quinze annos tem papo & nam tem mãos» [(Corpus do Português)](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/), que eu interpreto como ‘moço de quinze anos só tem garganta, prosápia’. Estas expressões aparecem ainda no século XIX. Mas saltando para o século XX encontramos em 1946 a expressão *contar papo*, ou melhor, *contá papo*, e *papudo* na [Revista do Arquivo Municipal (São Paulo) vol. 109-112:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=tSAv-lx602MC&q=papo&dq=papo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj45qLJqPfLAhWHuBoKHdB3DWEQ6AEITzAI)

> Papo — “conta papo”: contar bravatas ou valentias; “papo de cordão”: enorme bocio ou papo pendurado sobre o peito.
>
> Papudo — aquele que “conta papo” ou bravatas; também se diz garganta, prosa, jactancioso.

É precisamente nesta década que o [Google Books encontra os primeiros exemplos de *bate papo*](https://www.google.pt/search?q=%22bate%20papo%22&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=643&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1930%2Ccd_max%3A1950&tbm=bks). A primeira ocorrência é no Anuário Brasileiro de Literatura de 1940, mas o Google não mostra o texto. A ocorrência seguinte é de 1942 na [Revista do Instituto do Ceará:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=lig0AQAAIAAJ&q=%22bate%20papo%22&dq=%22bate%20papo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE8M3woffLAhWMVRQKHQzTBsE4ChDoAQhGMAU)

> No meu primeiro ***bate-papo***, deixei dito que Capistrano de Abreu era de trato pouco ameno. Se era? !

O primeiro exemplo de *bater papo* encontrei-o em *O Galo de Ouro* de Rachel de Queiroz, 1950:

> A menina era mansa, quase não dava trabalho à mãe, que por isso mesmo perdia horas com ela no braço, ***batendo papo*** pelos quartos das vizinhas.

Pelos vistos por esta altura *papo* já não significava necessariamente fanfarronice, mas [Antenor Nascentes em *A Gíria Brasileira* (1953)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=dSIrAAAAIAAJ&q=papo&dq=papo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij-Y36q_fLAhUK6xoKHZU5AsoQ6AEIPDAH) ainda define *bate-papo* como «conversa banal, tagarelice».

Parece-me portanto que apareceram primeiro as expressões *contar papo*,  *bate papo*, e só mais tarde *papo* começou a ser usado isoladamente com o significado de ‘conversa’. O primeiro exemplo que encontrei é de 1973 na revista [*Placar* (nº 187, p. 14-15), «Iustrich ataca: Roberto está jogando com muito medo»:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=c-YNo-J0n1MC&pg=PA15&dq=papo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjemI_NsPfLAhUFbBoKHZsgB7k4FBDoAQg3MAY#v=onepage&q=papo&f=false)

> Em São Paulo, Roberto continuou dizendo que Iustrich o está perseguindo […]
> ― Não quero ***papo*** com ele. A situação continua a mesma. Ele lá e eu cá. […] Aceito a ideia de mudar de time, de ser vendido ou emprestado para outro grande time. Com ele não tem mais ***papo***.

Finalmente em relação ao *bate*, *bater* é um verbo muito polivalente. Aqui temos uma lista de expressões publicadas no mesmo número da [*Revista do Arquivo Municipal* (São Paulo) vol. 109-112, 1946:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=tSAv-lx602MC&q=papo&dq=papo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj45qLJqPfLAhWHuBoKHdB3DWEQ6AEITzAI)

> Batê — “batê um chuvão”: chover muito; “batê as asas”: desaparecer; “batê uma pratada”: comer; “batê as bota”: morrer; “batê a carteira”: roubar; “batê boca”: discutir; “batê papo”: conversar.

A expressão semelhante [*bater boca* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/boca), como o sentido de discutir, altercar, encontra-se mais cedo, logo a partir de 1892: «Mas os senhores do Poço da Moita não batiam boca em suas terras» [(*Dona Guidinha do Poço* de Manoel de Oliveira Paiva).](http://www.santoandre.sp.gov.br/pesquisa/ebooks/344565.pdf).

Comment: Interessante, Jacinto. Obrigado pela resposta, muito detalhada.
É uma pena que haja poucos registos da expressão, e nenhum da transição de _contar papo_ para _bater papo_.
Sem esses registos deve ser praticamente impossível sabermos como _bater papo_ surgiu. Como não há nenhuma referência em Portugal, suponho que no Brasil ela foi inicialmente usada.

Comment: Registos de *bate papo* até há bastantes; só começam é em 1940. Estou até em crer que *contar papo* e *bater papo* terão evoluído paralelamente. Incluí o *contar papo* porque é mais transparente, dado que *papo* já antes estava associado a 'presunção'. Já consegui foi recuar *bater boca* a 1892. O que acontece é que estas expressões têm origem na linguagem oral, e só mais tarde é que passam à escrita. Isto teve tudo origem no Brasil, e nem se divulgaram muito em Portugal. Curiosamente, os primeiros exemplos escritos são todos do Ceará e São Paulo!

Comment: @felipe.zkn Também existe a palavra *papear*, que eu não incluí na resposta, que já ia longa, por não ver bem qual seria a sua relevância. Os dicionários atuais dizem que um dos seus significados é "conversar" e que vem de papo. Mas um dicionário do séc. XVIII define-a apenas como "palrar" ou "chirear". Encontrei uma meia dúzia de exemplos entre os séc. XVI e XX, e é com esses significados que aparece, não "conversar".